# Laravel: Filtrado con orWhere()

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-6, querybuilder

Buenas espero que estén bien, espero puedan orientarme, en mi interfaz tengo varios selects los cuales pueden ser escogidos por el usuario para filtrar diferentes datos en una tabla, sin embargo noto que mis condiciones orWhere no están funcionando como deberían. Lo que requiero es que si el usuario escoje 1, 2 o todas las opciones de los selects se filtre en base a ello ¿que podrían sugerirme?

Nota: Las variables que verán en la porción de código
contienen dentro de sí el string obtenido según el option de mi interfaz seleccionado, ya chequee estar recibiendo todo bien en mi controlador desde Ajax y chequee la salida, solo que esta es al azar no me toma mis condiciones **orWhere**.

Acá la porción del código de mi controlador:

```
->where('ownerop_id', 'like', '%'.$ownerop.'%')
->orWhere('broker_id', 'like', '%'.$broker.'%')
->orWhere('LOADSTATUS_ID', 'like', '%'.$loadStatus.'%')
->orWhere('all_loads.BILLING_STATUS_ID', 'like', '%'.$billingStatus.'%')
->orWhere('all_loads.dispatcher_id', 'like', '%'.$dispatcher.'%')
->orWhere('carrier_id', 'like', '%'.$carrier.'%')
```

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no creas un array con los filtros y pasas ese array en un sólo `where`, algo así: `->where($mParams)...` donde `$mParams` son todos los `WHERE` a aplicar. [En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522556/5587982) hay varios ejemplos.

Comment: Así como esta debería funcionar, cuando mencionas que no toma las condiciones `orWhere` te refieres a ninguna?, es decir todo se detiene y acaba en el `where`?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes partir el query builder realizando comparaciones y finalmente usar `get` o `first`

```
$items = Modelo::select(['columna1', 'columna2']);

if ($ownerop != '') {
    $items = $items->orWhere('ownerop_id', 'like', '%'.$ownerop.'%');
}

if ($broker != '') {
    $items = $items->orWhere('broker_id', 'like', '%'.$broker.'%');
}

$items = $items->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) dice que puedes pasar un array con varias cláusulas `where`:

```
You may also pass an array of conditions to the where function:

$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status', '=', '1'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```

Significa que en tu caso puedes crear un array con los parámetros y luego pasar ese array.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mParams=[
            ['ownerop_id', 'like', '%'.$ownerop.'%'],
            ['broker_id', 'like', '%'.$broker.'%'],
            ['LOADSTATUS_ID', 'like', '%'.$loadStatus.'%'],
            ['all_loads.BILLING_STATUS_ID', 'like', '%'.$billingStatus.'%'],
            ['all_loads.dispatcher_id', 'like', '%'.$dispatcher.'%'],
            ['carrier_id', 'like', '%'.$carrier.'%']
         ];
```

Y luego:

```
//...
->where($mParams)
//..
```

Esto es particularmente útil cuando `$mParams` se crea de forma dinámica.

Comment: Sin embargo si el OP indica que busca  que 1, 2 **o** mas condiciones se cumplan *(pero no todas a la vez)* entonces la consulta propuesta no le va a funcionar ya que aquí el query builder leería una serie de `WHERE algo  = algo AND otro = otro AND otro2 = otro2 AND otro3 = otro3 ...etc` y no se esta usando el operador OR como el busca