# Busqueda en laravel 7 en dos columnas a la vez con el mismo input

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, busqueda, like

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda desde un *input search*, pero me gustaría que la consulta con la palabra clave, tomara en cuenta varios campos como `nombre` `apellido_paterno` y `apellido_materno` para devolver los resultados, ya sea que la palabra que encuentre en el nombre, apellido_paterno o apellido paterno

```
usuarios::where('nombre','apellido_paterno','apellido_materno', "%$juan perez perez%")->get();
```

(algo asi)

Hasta el momento solo puedo buscar por un campo el nombre.
espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula [**`orWhere()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses) para que la búsqueda filtre a las 3 columnas:

```
usuarios::where('nombre', 'like', '%juan perez perez%')
        ->orWhere('apellido_paterno', 'like', '%juan perez perez%')
        ->orWhere('apellido_materno', 'like', '%juan perez perez%')
        ->get();
```

O si utilizas variables, puede quedar como esto:

```
usuarios::where('nombre', 'like', '%'.$value.'%')
        ->orWhere('apellido_paterno', "like", '%'.$value.'%')
        ->orWhere('apellido_materno', "like", '%'.$value.'%')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte pero ya lo e utilizado, pero hay algo que no se que pasé  que no me respeta esa sentencia. será posible de otra forma?

Comment: Claro, puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594588/laravel-eloquent-multiple-where-with-or-and-or-and-like) o también [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335232/laravel-filtrado-con-orwhere), me guie de aquí y traté de acercarme más a tu solución. También hubieras mencionado los intentos que hiciste y los errores que ocurre, así podría haberte dado otras soluciones.